# Why the gaslimit of the contract transaction be set much larger than the usage for executed?

Tags: solidity, contract

Failed: gas:313,403 | 305,116 (97.36%)
https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xa32a0df5fc02868fb2aab3b10d4a00596fec3a2a62122fdabd40d651b36ab847

Success: gas:415,841 | 287,893 (69.23%)
https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xab7c8a675e0c421c855665743a32ca6fd636c7588aee0a03a750dc6dadaaf623

The same tx data. In the success tx gasused is 287,893,
I have try it by estimateGas is 287000~
But if I set the galimit 313,403, it's still failed.
Why?

Comment: do you use remix and set the gas limit manually?

Comment: I used ethers.js,  that's rather strange, the two transactions are roughly the same except for the salt of the parameter.